# C# Загрузка больших данных из БД , как организовать

Tags: c#

В какую структуру данных загрузить большую таблицу , есть запрос с порядка миллиона записей из таблицы , во что запихнуть или как-то по частям можно запрос распихать в DataTable ?Потом это необходимо все обработать и выполнять другие запросы к этим выборкам?

Comment: Все зависит от того, что вы с данными делать собрались. Например, если данные можно обработать построчно, то нет смысла их все грузить в память

Comment: Так с БД, точнее с СУБД не работают. Сервер СУБД должен делать выборки и проч. манипуляции с данными, а не клиентский софт. Иначе получается, что вы используете сервер как тупое хранилище данных, это неправильно. Используйте хранимые процедуры, обрабатывайте данные на самом сервере и лишь только результаты передавайте на клинетскую сторону.